# Java compiler errors in grails application

Tags: java, grails, javacc

I have a grails application with a JavaCC parser integrated. In this parser I create grails domain object. I have objects such as Product, Release and Document as Grails domain classes.

In the generated Java class (from JavaCC) I create Products, Releases and Documents. Very often (not always though) I get build errors from Grails stating that:

`Compile error during compilation with javac.
D:\workspaces\productArchive\com.rcs.products\src\java\com\configinfo\Parser.java:173: error: cannot find symbol
                                document.setFilename(filename);
                                        ^
  symbol:   method setFilename(String)
  location: variable document of type Document`

My Document class looks like this:

```
class Document {
 String filename     
 String docVersion
 String path
 String title
 String documentNumber
 String keys


    static belongsTo = [release: Release]

    static constraints = {
        filename(blank: false)
        version(blank: false)
        path(blank: true)
        release(nullable: true)
        keys(blank: true, nullable: true)
    }

}
```

I have set JDK_VERSION to 1.6 in the JavaCC grammar file. I'm using Grails 2.0.1.

Can anyone explain these compiler errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to some kind of name collison. I don't know why though.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose to put Document class into package and try to rename

```
String filename
```

to

```
String nameOfFile
```